# What is the purpose of this op amp configuration shown?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I've been researching common amplifier configurations, but the only ones with positive feedback that I have discovered is a negative resistance simulator, however that has negative feedback too.

Comment: I think the point is for you to work out what it does for yourself.

Comment: Voting to close homework with no research or attempt at solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working as a comparator basically.

> It is a Schmitt trigger. It has a variable reference value, i.e. controlled using the R2 and R1 resistances. At the non-inverting input (using voltage divider arrangement), $$V_+ = \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} * V_{o}$$ and at inverting input, $$ V_- = Vi $$ at the inverting terminal. Now, output can be either \$ +V_s \$ or \$ -V_s \$ depending on whether non-inverting terminal voltage is higher or not respectively. So, the output is \$\beta V_s\$ or \$-\beta V_s \$ where \$ \beta = \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \$. If first output is in positive saturation and then \$V_i\$ goes above \$\beta V_s\$, then output changes to \$-V_s\$. Similarly, when \$V_i\$ goes below \$-\beta V_s\$, then output changes to \$ +V_s\$. You can find a lot of websites that explain this circuit. Just search for Schmitt trigger.

Comment: We don't encourage giving complete answers like this to homework questions with no attempt at a solution. If we did the site would be swamped. Instead, you can give a prompt to start them in the right direction if you're happy they've done some research first. Further prompts can be given as they update the question to show their progress.

Comment: I agree, and I tried to format it as a spoiler (blockquote), but that feature is not working for some reason. Just the first line of my answer is enough to nudge anyone in the right direction, so if anyone can format it like a spoiler (blockquote), please do so.

Comment: Use `>!` markup for spoiler but I doubt that anyone who is getting us to do their homework would have any qualms about revealing the answer.

Comment: I would still request you to not be so harsh since sometimes it's difficult to get the approach until you find it from someone or some book or the Internet. But, once you do get the approach, it becomes easier to extend it to other problems (and in this case, I don't think the OP even thought that the op-amp could be working as a comparator, they were thinking on the lines of simple differential amplifiers with feedback). Nevertheless, I will make sure I don't post direct answers in future.

Comment: Points understood, but when you've been around a while you will be amazed at what people expect to get away with. Not understanding is one thing but asking us to do their homework is another. These guys might be competing for your job in a few years!